# How to do automatic mysql db backup using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database-backups

How to do automatic mysql db backup using mysql workbench?

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a webserver with PHP I'd suggest [MySqlDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/)

It supports:

- Automatic backups
- Emails backups
- Compresses backups
- Rotates backups
- etc.

Comment: MySqlDumper? Instructions are bad.

Answer (score 10):

Mysql bench is not required for automatic backup,
setup a crontab and use mysqldump (or equivalent) will do the same job and is easier.

example:

```
crontab -e

/* backup every day at 00:00:00 */
0 0 * * * mysqldump -u root -ppassword YOUR_DATABASE > /backup/YOUR_DATABASE.sql
```

Comment: I'm currently using task scheduler for windows to do that. I just want to learn other methods of doing it, that's why I asked. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Of course  you *might* want to actually wrap a little script around that to rotate the backups using some sort of aging system (like keep every daily for that last week, every weekly for the last quarter and every quarterly forever ... or something like that).  Might want to use `~/.my.cnf` to hide your admin/root password there rather in the cron subsystem.

Comment: While I personally prefer mysqldump, it may be easier in some case to use Workbench functionality (e.g. it is really difficult for novices to make partial restore from huge mysqldump backup).

Answer (score 1):

ATM scheduled backups are not plannned in Workbench:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50074

At the same time Workbench is designed to have powerful scripting shell, so you can try to 
investigate what commands can be used for backup and call them directly from shell.
(But I agree this is too general idea):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-extending.html