# How to backup MySQL with MySQL workbench automatically

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Guys I'm using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Is there a way to use it to backup my database automatically?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532649/how-to-do-automatic-mysql-db-backup-using-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer is **There is no backup scheduling/automating option** in MySQL Workbench as of 6.2. You can do manual backup in version 6.x by clicking on DataExport under Management. See below:

[MySQL WorkBench Data Export Import](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html)

Comment: as of 2023, is there now a way ?

Answer (score 1):

http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=11972

> Making a backup in MySQL workbench is a pretty easy task, but it can
>   be hard to find exactly where to do it the first time around.
>   Typically when you're working in MySQL Workbench you will be using the
>   SQL Development section. But in order to export a backup you have to
>   move to the Server Administration section.
>
> The first time through you will have to Create A New Server Instance.
>   If you have already set up the connection parameters in the SQL
>   Development section, you can just choose Take Parameters from Existing
>   Database Connection.
>
> MySQL Workbench will then test the connection.
>
> In the "Remote Management Type" dialog, select Do not use remote
>   management.
>
> Create Instance Profile is just asking you for a name for the
>   connection. You can enter whatever you'd like here.
>
> When you make the connection in the Server Administration section you
>   will see a notice that remote administration is disabled. But don't
>   worry, you can still make a backup of your database.

```
Click the Data Dump tab to access the export utility.
Check the box for the database you want to back up
Choose Export to Self-Contained File and make sure the path is correct.
Hit the Start Export button.
```

Edit:
I am using mysql administrator, which has schedule option. check this also:

http://www.davecolorado.com/index.php/scheduled-backup-with-mysql-administrator-on-windows/

Comment: I think by "automatically", the OP meant without user intervention, so scheduled, periodic, automatic backups

Comment: Your post's bottom link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can use Create Event in `MySql workbench` to create automated backups. Sample code:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS test_event_01
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
  INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at)
  VALUES('Test MySQL Event 1',NOW());
```

Check this link for more details:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/