# MySQL Workbench scheduled backup utility

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, database-backups

[I posted the query below to the [Database Admin StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84289/mysql-scheduled-backup-utility) site but was put on hold due to being off-topic, which came as a wee surprise. I hope that it's not OT for StackOverflow. ]

My (medium-sized) organisation uses the excellent MySQL Workbench 6.1 Community for DB management. Workbench used to have a scheduled backup tool built in, IIRC, but no longer - you have to buy the Enterprise Edition for this.

So I've a quick question: what cheap/Open Source utilities are available to plugin in Workbench to configure and run scheduled backups of selected or all DB? By 'backup', I mean a nightly SQL dump of N DBs. There is a thread [at Automatic backup MySQL Workbench](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74412/automatic-backup-mysql-workbench) but that references fairly heavy-duty tools. [Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430876/how-to-backup-mysql-with-mysql-workbench-automatically) on here refers to an outdated Workbench version.

We can use a batch file (it's a Windoze server) to schedule backups, but for futureproofing and for the sake of my successor(s) it would be nice to have an easy-to-use GUI tool. Any recommendations?

Comment: Your question wasn't closed as off-topic.  It was closed as a shopping list, which none of the Stack Exchange sites like because they stop being useful very quickly.  The only MySQL free backup utility I've used is `mysqldump.exe` that ships with it, but it's not a GUI.  Write up a document for how backup works and save it with the rest.  If you get hit by a bus, the next guy will be able to find your doc and figure it out.

Comment: (shrug) I thought it was marked as off-topic based on "This question appears to be off-topic for this site". I'll remember for next time. Code Qs only on Stack*.

Answer (score 0):

There's no free tool or plugin for MySQL Workbench to schedule backups. However with MySQL Enterprise Backup (in short MEB) you can do that, including management from within MySQL Workbench. MEB is however a commercial solution for MySQL.